# How to trigger a function when the typing cursor leaves the input text field?

Tags: javascript

I want to trigger a function when the typing cursor leaves the input text field. Does such an event exists? If someone knows please let me know, Thanks.

```
// to trigger this function
function trigger () {
    console.log("no longer able to type in input text);
}
```

Comment: look into `onblur`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just use onblur. You can do this in both vanilla js and jquery.

Vanilla Js:

```js
function test() {
  alert('Exited');
}

document.getElementById('waffle').addEventListener('blur', function(){
  alert('exited waffle');
});
```

```html
<input type="text" onblur="test()">
<input type="text" id="waffle">
```

With JQuery:

```js
$('#test').on('blur', function(){
  alert('exited');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="test" type="text">
```

Jquery Ref: https://api.jquery.com/blur/

Vanilla: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/blur

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is an event that you can bind a function to called "blur". It looks like this if you use `addEventListener()`:

```js
document.getElementById("myInput").addEventListener("blur", function() {
    alert("focused out");
});
```

```html
<input id="myInput"/>
```

Or if you have a named function, `myFunction`, you can register it on the DOM element via the input tag:

```js
function myFunction() {
    alert("focused out");
};
```

```html
<input onblur="myFunction()"/>
```